# Resource from mediaelement blocked due to MIME type mismatch

Tags: drupal-7, mediaelement

I'm trying to fix a hacked site for someone so I am not sure why this is happening:

The resource from “https://xxx.ca/sites/xxxx/libraries/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js?v=4” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). xxx.ca

I've installed mediaelement in my libraries folder and also in the modules folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I may have solved the problem by searching the hacked site ... the folder in the Library folders has different contents from the module but I could not find a source for that folder not information on how it was to be used. So I have copied it hoping it isn't hacked.

Comment: make latest security core update from Drupal community and check all permissions on crucial folders : https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Comment: I reinstalled the source code and seem to have solved the problem.